# Why doesnt work edit model by list_filter with custom model manager?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

For Post model I created a custom manager:

```
#models.py
class ObjectsOnManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ObjectsOnManager, self).get_queryset().filter(status='on')


class OnOffStatusModel(models.Model):
    ON = 'on'
    OFF = 'off'
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (ON, 'Показывать'),
        (OFF, 'Не показывать'),
    )
    status = models.CharField("Статус", max_length=15, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=ON)
    objects_on = ObjectsOnManager()
    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Post(OnOffStatusModel):
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField("Показы", default=0)
    title = models.CharField("Заголовок", max_length=50)
    descript = models.CharField("Описание", max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='posts')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField("Дата публикации", default=timezone.now, blank=True)
    body = models.TextField("Текст поста", max_length=2500)
    main_post = models.BooleanField("Главная новость", default=False)
```

Then changed get_queryset in modelAdmin

```
#admin.py
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PostImageControlForm
    fields = ('count', 'status',  'image',  'title', 'descript', 'body', 'main_post', )
    list_display = ('title', 'main_post', 'count',)
    list_editable = ('main_post', 'status')
    list_filter = ('category', 'main_post', 'status')

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return Post.objects.all()
```

So if I edit model on the change model page it is ok, but if i tried to edit on the change list page I have got the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puWiR.png)

Comment: You need to get the error from the formset to see what your issue is. Are you familiar with how to debug your application? You need to add a breakpoint in django/contrib/admin/options.py in the changelist_view function after the formset has been validated

Comment: Can you share the rest of your `Post` model? Especially the `main_post` field

Comment: formset.errors: [{'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {}, {}, {}, {}]

Comment: added fields in question